# Alamofire 4.0: timeoutIntervalForRequest

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift3

How to set timeoutIntervalForRequest in Alamofire 4.0 and swift 3.0.

Bellow code working for me swift 2.2 and Alamofire 3.0.

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is how I do it.

```
SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300
```

Alternatively,

```
var configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300;
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```